# When/why was "so" dropped in "whomsoever"?

Tags: etymology, pronouns

My association with the words

> whomsoever
>   whosoever

has been through the Bible, more modern day they have become

> whomever
>   whoever

As an example, John 13:20

> He that receiveth whom**so**ever I send receiveth me. *(King James Version)*
>   he who receives whomever I send receives Me *(New American Standard)*

The New American Standard version is a more "modern" translation.

When and why did the "so" disappear?
I have tried searching, but can find when/why the change occurred.

Comment: Here's the full set of such words from the OED: *however, howsoever, howsomever, ifsoever, whatever, whatsoever,
whatsomever, whencesoever, whencever, whenever, whensoever, whensomever,
whereinsoever, wheresoever, wheresomever, wherever, whethersoever,
whichever, whichsoever, whilever, whithersoever, whoever, whomever,
whomsoever, whomsomever, whosesoever, whosever, whosoever, whosomever, whyever.*

Comment: Warm welcome to ELU. The *so* still appears on "whatsoever" which means "at all" for emphasis in a negative sentence. I don't think it has disappeared **yet** but [usage has declined over the years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=marry+whoever%2C+marry+whomsoever&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmarry%20whoever%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmarry%20whomsoever%3B%2Cc0). ,

Comment: It's been pinched to start sentences.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Pinched"? Shortened?

Comment: Nabbed. Appropriated. Sequestered. Filched. (I am not suggesting this for serious consideration.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: So, that's one of my pet peeves also. ;-) Much as my old-fogey ears can filter out superfluous *Well,...*, I find habitual *So,...* quite annoying.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite so! You've overlooked 'trousered' in the scheme of things filched and the like.

Comment: Why the scare-quotes round 'modern'? I'd think they'd be better round the 'archaic' versions. If a modern translation is somehow less than acceptable, so is a translation into any language other than the original ones.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602701).

Answer (score 1):

Whosoever and whomsoever derive from the archaic Middle English  pronouns "***[whoso](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whoso), [whomso](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whomso)***". Their usage is still present but it is less common and formal. According to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whoever%2Cwhosoever%2Cwhoso&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhoever%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhosoever%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhoso%3B%2Cc0)***  "whoever and whomever" have been more widely used  since the mid 18th century.

> - whoso took such things into account was a fool’
>
>   - ***archaic term for whoever***

***[Whosoever](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whosoever?s=t):***

> - pronoun;, (possessive whosesoever; objective whomsoever.)

Origin:

> - 1175-1225 -  Middle English; From: ***whoso +  ever***

ODO

Comment: Thank you, but why the change?

Comment: @Peter - why in the mid of the 18th century writers stared to prefer whoever to whosoever is hard tell, maybe whosoever was considered more formal also at that time being commonly found in books like the Bibble for instance.