# Possessive case with who(m)ever in an object noun phrase

Tags: possessives, objects, noun-phrases, possessive-determiners, whoever-vs-whomever

## Disclaimer

[The question put forward as the pretext for mine's closure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552178/whomever-as-both-object-and-subject) does not answer my question at all—that question contains “who(m)ever” in a clause acting as an object, which I have no trouble with. My question deals with a possessive contained inside a *noun phrase*, which is much more complex. Therefore, I request that my question remain open.

## Question

> Parents should use who(m)ever's last name is shorter on the form.

Should *whoever* or *whomever* be used in the above sentence? The way I see it, “who(m)ever's last name is shorter” is a **noun phrase** (NP) acting as the **object** of the verb *use*, while “who(m)ever's” is seemingly acting as the **head** of this NP<sup>[1]</sup> (more specifically, as a possessive determiner formed from a relative pronoun—how the relative clause looks like, I'm failing to figure out—and the clitic *'s*, with another clause after that to modify the head?).

So, how should it conform to the sentence?

Should “whoever's” be used here? The following sentence makes perfect sense to me:

> Whoever's (whosever) last name is shorter should be used on the form.

since “whoever” is acting as the head of the NP which is the **subject** of the sentence. However, here, “who**m**ever” is acting as the head of a NP which is the **object** of the sentence, which throws me off and makes an argument for “who**m**ever” appear more compelling in my mind:

> Whoever's last name is shorter [...], parents should use it.

since the NP is **replacing the object** *it*, and the pronoun should be an **object pronoun**.

Is my grammatical analysis correct? Is there a general rule of thumb to use when encountering sentences like these? I am not a grammarist of any kind, so I'd prefer it if you kept your answers in simple terms! I greatly appreciate any and all of your thoughts on this matter!

## Notes

1. According to the [determiner phrase (DP) hypothesis/analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase), also used as an answer in [this English Stack Exchange question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566268/whomever-vs-whoever-possessive). I'm using “head of the NP” instead of “head of the DP” for consistency and to avoid confusion.

Comment: I chose a duplicate which explains that "whoever's last name" is the subject of *is* and the **whole phrase** "whoever's last name is shorter" is the object of *use*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Whomever’s* is never viable — not as a possessive, not as a contraction, not anywhere. That leaves *whosever* and *whoever’s* as possibilities (see **Later** at end for more on that).

You have already learned this:

A dependent clause headed up by *whoever* or *whomever* is not affected by the role it plays in the sentence — subject, object . . . it doesn’t matter. The clause must be grammatically true unto itself.

Compare the clauses ***whoever likes him*** (where *whoever* is the subject of *likes*) and ***whomever he likes*** (where *whomever* is the object of *likes*). And then compare these sentences, all correct:

> *Whoever* **clause** as subject: ***Whoever likes him** gets candy*.
> *Whoever* **clause** as object: *He gives candy to **whoever likes him***.
> *Whomever* **clause** as subject: ***Whomever he likes** gets candy*.
> *Whomever* **clause** as object: *He gives candy to **whomever he likes***.

All that said, this hardly applies to your example. A possessive can never be a subject or an object; it’s a modifying interloper on its way to the subject or object. Its sole job is to serve its modificand.

Compare the clauses *whosever **cat likes him*** (where *cat* is the subject of *likes*) and *whosever **cat he likes*** (where *cat* is the object of *likes*). And then compare these sentences, all correct (if you can abide *whosever* — see **Later** at end):

> *Cat* **clause** as subject: *Whosever **cat likes him** gets chow.*
> *Cat* **clause** as object: *He gives chow to whosever **cat likes him**.*
> *Cat* **clause** as subject: *Whosever **cat he likes** gets chow.*
> *Cat* **clause** as object: *He gives chow to whosever **cat he likes**.*

No *whomsever* or *whomever’s*.

**Later . . . *whosever* vs. *whoever’s***

*Whosever* is rare in usage. For most natural results, use *whoever’s* instead of *whosever*. *Oxford English Dictionary* (among others) straight up calls *whosever* “rare” and offers a scant two usage examples, ending at 1865:

> **whosever**, *pron.*
> *rare.*
>  The genitive of WHOEVER *pron.*: = WHOSESOEVER *pron*.
>  <sub>1739    ‘R. BULL’ tr. F. Dedekind *Grobianus* 133  
> Whos’ever Knife upon the Table lies.</sub>
>  <sub>1865    W. G.
> PALGRAVE *Narr. Journey through Arabia* II. 19    Whosever the
> footprint may be, the story is gospel among Mahometans.</sub>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

So:

> *Whoever’s cat likes him gets chow.*
> *He gives chow to whoever’s cat likes him.*
> *Whoever’s cat he likes gets chow.*
> *He gives chow to whoever’s cat he likes.*

*Whoever’s* all around.

<sub>Further reading: [Garner’s Usage Tip of the Day: whoever; whomever.](https://lawprose.org/garners-usage-tip-of-the-day-whoever-whomever/)</sub>

Comment: Good! [But let whosoever says it's rare check this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whosever%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzUrgXPGayK7Q8SmdQgsuDQ5uZsKVw%3A1675562877127&ei=fQ_fY8SzB_Hz9APh17noAQ&ved=0ahUKEwiE5tuQpv38AhXxOX0KHeFrDh0Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22whosever%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BQghEKsCOgUIABCABFCDDViTFGDrFGgAcAB4AIAB9gGIAdgIkgEFMS43LjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books), particularly Bryan Garner’s *Modern American English*, [elsewhere cited in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/446474).

Comment: But "who(m)ever likes him" is not a clause but an NP in a fused relative construction.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow you are overthinking this terribly and coming to a nonsensical conclusion. You ask us to choose between incorrect assumptions.

> > Parents should use who(m)ever's last name is shorter on the form.
>
> Should *whoever* or *whomever* be used in the above sentence?

No, they should not. You've got it all wrong.

Just as the possessive form of *he* is *his* **not** ❌ *he’s*, the possessive form of *who* is *whose* **not** *who’s*.

And there is no possessive form of *whom*: it is already the object form. If you need a possessive, you go back to the correct possessive, which I repeat is *whose*. For the same reason that there is no such word as ❌ *him’s*,  [there is no such word as ❌ *whom’s*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/446474/2085)!

**Whose** name is shorter? **His** name is shorter. Not who's name is shorter, not he's name is shorter, not him's name is shorter. And it doesn't matter one weaselly whit whether *his name* is the subject or the object. None. Don't touch it. It simply doesn't matter whether you need to use that noun phrase as a subject or as an object. Your possessive determiner **does not change to him's or whom's or whomseverses's** or any other crazy thing.

Do this and don't look back:

1. Whosever name is shorter wins.
2. Use whosever name is shorter.

Or colloquially:

1. Whoever's name is shorter wins.
2. Use whoever's name is shorter.

After all, you don't say "Use him's name". So don't try to do those other weird things either.

Comment: The OP has a valid point. There is a clash between the function of the whole NP and the relativised element, as I pointed out here: [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/594178/to-whomever-asks-vs-to-whoever-asks/594240?noredirect=1#comment1519303_594240)

Comment: @BillJ Either I misunderstand you, or else I disagree — because I recognize no valid logic that admits as grammatical transformations such as
✅ *a friend of his* > ❌ *a friend of him’s*;
✅ *a friend of his mother’s* > ❌ *a friend of him’s mother’s*;
✅ *call his friend* > ❌ *call him’s friend*;
✅ *call whoever asked* > ❌ *call whomever asked*;
✅ *call who is coming* > ❌ *call whom is coming*;
✅ *call whose friends asked about him* > ❌ *call whom’s friends asked about him*;
✅ *call whosever friends asked about his status* > ❌ *call whomever’s friends asked about him’s status*.

Comment: @BillJ: tchrist's point is that *whomever's* is neither nominative or accusative, it's genitive, just like *who* is nominative, *whom* is accusative, and *whose* is genitive.  And in any event, it's just not used. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+whoever+%27+s%2Cfor+whomever+%27+s%2Cfor+whosever&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: Yes, informal "whoever's" is genitive. It occurs in fused relatives in the free choice construction, but hardly elsewhere.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/417271/2085).

Answer (score -1):

> Parents should use **who(m)ever's last name is shorter** on the form.

who(m)ever's = the person whose

> Parents should use **the person whose last name is shorter** on the
> form.

Can we use a person on a form?

> **Whoever's** horse wins will get the prize.

Does a person get the prize or their horse?

> He whose horse wins will get the prize
>
> We give the prize to him whose horse wins.

**He whose** own life is without intrinsic value can not recognize intrinsic value in another. (Joseph A. Leighton; 1937)

"The Relation of Literature to Life" will not appeal to **him whose** main object in reading is amusement. (Warner, Charles Dudley; 1896)

Would the two above make sense with **Whoever's** and **whomever's** respectively? Would it improve them?

I don't believe these questions have a correct answer, but do think that, whenever there is any doubt at all, **whoever's** is preferable given a binary choice since anything with **whom** feels a bit formal, dated even, and can be replaced by **who** without anyone batting too large an eyelash.

Further, while the genitive form **whoever's** can be found in HANSARD (British Parliament Corpus) and COHA (Corpus of Historical American English), **whomever's** has only a single hit in COHA and no representation at all in HANSARD, and then the single hit in COHA isn't the genitive form but a clitic.

Comment: But the question revolves around whether nominative "whoever's" or accusative "whomever's" is correct, doesn't it?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, it does. The asker requested that we not get too far into grammatical details and provide a general rule of thumb for situations like these, both of which requests I attempted to honor with my reply.